# Recyclerview checkbox are checked when not clicked

Tags: java, android

I have a Recyclerview with checkboxes. When a user checks a box, when they scroll down another box will already be checked. I understand why, because that box is being recycled which makes sense.

But I am having issues to set it so it does not do this:

My current onBindViewHolder:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position){

    holder.playerNameNumber.setText(playerData.get(position).name + "\n" +playerData.get(position).number );

    holder.pickedPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View thisView){
            PlayerDetails contact = new PlayerDetails();
            int contactPos = position;
            if(holder.pickedPlayer.isChecked()) {

                contact.number = playerData.get(position).number;
                contact.name = playerData.get(position).name;
                playerListGame.addPlayer(contact);
                String name = contact.name;
                Toast.makeText(thisView.getContext(), name + " Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                holder.pickedPlayer.setChecked(true);
            }
           else if(!holder.pickedPlayer.isChecked()){
                contact.number = playerData.get(position).number;
                contact.name = playerData.get(position).name;
                for(PlayerDetails i : playerListGame.myPlayers){
                    if(i.name == contact.name && i.number == contact.number){
                        contactPos = playerListGame.myPlayers.indexOf(i);
                    }
                }
                playerListGame.removePlayer(contactPos);
                String name = contact.name;
                Toast.makeText(thisView.getContext(), name + " Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });


}
```

Now I know that SetIsRecyclable is a big no no, though it does fix my problem:

```
  public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            playerNameNumber = v.findViewById(R.id.playerDetails);
            pickedPlayer =v.findViewById(R.id.
              this.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

How do I avoid using such a method to resolve this issue?

Comment: check myanswer hope it help...mark as correct if fit your needs @trig

Comment: i updated it check  again @trig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        holder.pickedPlayer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        //define private boolean selected with setter and getter
        holder.pickedPlayer.setChecked(playerData.isSelected());
        holder.pickedPlayer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
            playerData.setSelected(isChecked);
            if (isChecked)
            {
               Toast.makeText(context,"checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"not checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: does not like playerData.IsSelected(); not sure what I need to enable this

Comment: define Boolean variable called Selected with its getter and setter in your calssmodel @trig

Comment: Coolio, will give it ago. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a boolean into your dataset also.so when user check or uncheck a box that time update the boolean value of respected position’s dataset and call notify item changed

```
arraylist.get(pos).setDataCheked(true);
notifyItemChanged(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set  the current value of the checkbox just like you're setting the player name and number. I've assumed it's called something like picked in your playerData.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.playerNameNumber.setText(playerData.get(position).name + "\n" +playerData.get(position).number );
    holder.pickedPlayer.setChecked(playerData.get(position).picked);

    // same onclick listener, removed for readability
}
```